# why initializing varaible within try block does not persist outside?

Tags: java, try-catch

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int a;
        // for( a=0; a<5; a++ ){}
        try {
            a=10;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO: handle exception
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

In the above code, initialization to var `a` by for loop persists while printing it, but not with try block.

Comment: Are you getting a compile error *variable a might not have been initialized*?

Comment: You have created a path through your code in which a might not be initialised.

Comment: Note: you really want to read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: @JoSSte An `int` cannot have a `NullPointerException` as it cannot be null. As far as the compile is concerned, there is a code-path (the catch block) that doesn't initialize `a`, so it simply disallows it.

Comment: good point - couldn't edit it - so removed my comment instead

Answer (score 2):

The java compiler doesn't know what is going to happen in the try block.

The whole point of the try/catch is: there is some code that *might* execute fine, or might not. Therefore the assignment to `a` inside the try block is not guaranteed to happen, therefore the following **read access** to `a` might find it as (still) not initialized.

The real answer: there are many situations where a human reader can see "there is no problem here". But the java compiler fails to recognize that special case. Of course, one *could* write a compiler that detects "a is assigned a value, and that code will never throw an exception". But the java compiler isn't written that way. That is all there is to this.

Comment: Change "meaningless" to "not guaranteed", and "invalid" to "uninitialized"?